# Text of select Menu inside of a span

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown

```
   <select id="select_domain">
   <option value="1">Jon Doe</option>
   <option value="2">Max Mustermann</option>
   </select>
```

And a span

```
<span id="domain"></span>
```

Inside this span there should be the text of the selected option of my select menu.

How can i do this with jQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is what you expected:

```js
 $("#select_domain").on("change", function() {
   $("#domain").text($("#select_domain option:selected").text());
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_domain">
  <option value="1">Jon Doe</option>
  <option value="2">Max Mustermann</option>
</select>
<span id="domain"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this answer,

```
$(function() {
    $('#select_domain').change(function(){
        $("#domain").text($("#select_domain option:selected").text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use to get the text :

```
$("#select_domain option:selected").text();
```

and to get the value :

```
$("#select_domain").val()
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/eqd22pca/1/

Answer (score 2):

The "when" is kind of important, but if you want your span to update when you select a new value, use something like this:

```
    $( "#select_domain" ).change(function() {
       $('#domain').html($('select_domain').val());
    });
```

If you want the default value to show in the span on load, you can do that with your server side code or add this line to your generic function:

```
    $('#domain').html($('select_domain').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explained example, along with the extra effect of triggering the event on page load.

```js
/*Binds a change event to your select*/
$('#select_domain').change(function () {
    /*sets the text to the selected option of THIS select box*/
    set_text($('option:selected', this).text());
});
/*Creates a function to set the text of domain
This function can be used elsewhere as well*/
function set_text(text){
    $('#domain').text(text);
}

/*This triggers the function and sets the text 
to the currently selected text on page load*/
set_text($('#select_domain option:selected').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_domain">
    <option value="1">Jon Doe</option>
    <option value="2">Max Mustermann</option>
</select>
<span id="domain"></span>
```